# Amazon EC2 or RDS for SQL server deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to host my sql server database on the cloud using amazon web services. Do I need to buy EC2 or RDS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question, because EC2 != RDS

One is a server, a deployed OS (EC2), which can be Windows, Linux, etc

While the other is a database (you don't see the OS behind it)

So you cannot compare the two, each has its own function

If you are looking for a "hassle free" (depends on end-goal) database, RDS is the best option, requires "zero knowledge" of how to install an OS, maintain it, install packages, etc - it does require other types of knowledge which are RDS specific

Comment: Can I host a database on EC2?

Comment: Yes EC2 is an OS, do whatever you want on it, mine bitcoin, install a web server, anything its yours to use

Comment: That's great! I got the perfect person to answer. Thank you.

Comment: I need to host ASP.Net website, WCF web services and some .Net utilities. I need to install Cassandra and Couchbase on the server. Can I do all these things with EC2?

Comment: As mentioned before, more than one EC2 gives you a running OS at the end. So in your case, install Windows (Server), IIS, .NET etc, and get yourself the environment you want.